# Why is ag-theme-balham the only ag-grid theme that works?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I added `ag-grid` to my Angular project. Then I imported its CSS into `styles.css`.

```
@import "~@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

So far, so good. The `ag-theme-balham` theme shows up when I run the app.

However, now I want to change the theme. But no matter which other theme's CSS I choose, no styling shows up. Even `ag-theme-balham-dark` doesn't work.

**Verified:**

- The other themes' CSS files exist in `node_modules`.
- The Angular project compiles.
- There are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ag-grid-angular` has a class attribute that you have to update as well:

```html
<ag-grid-angular 
    *ngIf="rowData"
    style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" 
    class="ag-theme-balham"    <!-- Update this -->
    [rowData]="rowData" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [modules]="modules">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: Is there any way I can set this globally?

Answer (score 2):

Certain themes are available only in the updated version of ag-grid. You may want to check the availability with respect to the version that you are using.

For more information:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-themes-provided/

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-themes-v23-migration/